# Cache image and show them using Haneke

Tags: ios, swift, caching, haneke

I'm trying to cache ([Haneke](https://github.com/Haneke/HanekeSwift)) an image and show it but i can't seem to figure out the first UIImage parameter in the `hnk_setImage`. How can i show the image from the `logoCache` key?

**Cache Image**

```
cache.set(value: logoData, key: logoCache)
```

**Fetch and Show Image**

```
cell.customerImageView?.hnk_setImage(UIImage?, key: logoCache)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var mArray = [[String:AnyObject]]()
```

inside `cellForItemAtIndexPath` function

```
var var1 = mArray[indexPath.row]

    let ImageURLKey = var1["logoCache"] as! String

if let url =  NSURL(string: "yourUrl/"+ImageURLKey) {
        cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
         cell.imageView.hnk_setImageFromURL(url)

    }
```

Comment: How is this an answer to the question?